# Remote browser access to Windows CE/Mobile/Embedded emulators?

Tags: emulation, compact-framework

My company has a Compact Framework.NET WinForms application which runs on rugged handhelds manufactured by companies like Motorola, Intermec and Psion.  These are expensive devices with built-in barcode scanners that are used in harsh conditions.

The configuration of the handheld application is managed by business users through our web site.  The devices pick up the configuration when they sync from within the handheld application.  Field workers use the handhelds, business users use the web site.

The business users have expressed the desire to, for lack of a better description, configure and preview or even fully use the actual handheld application through a web browser.  They want to make configuration changes in the web site and immediately see what the impact will be in the handheld, without having to have a physical device (again, the devices are quite expensive).  They want to be able to create training materials or conduct sales meetings and be able to demonstrate the application to their customers without having a physical device on hand.

Microsoft offers several Device Emulators, but they are probably too complex for business users. They are developer tools.  One idea might be to somehow use the emulators within virtual machines possibly in conjunction with Terminal Services or even some kind of clever screen capture/VNC to show an emulated device in a browser.  I suspect running emulators in the fashion may not exactly be a scalable solution, however. Also, only one emulator at a time on a single machine can be "cradled" and connected to network.

I'm looking for any suggestions which might help me meet the business users' requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: After much caffeinated discussion, we are going to set off in the direction of investigating if we can make the CF.NET app run successfully on a Windows desktop. This could open the door to a self-updating ClickOnce application that our Windows users could use to "emulate" a mobile device. It could also enable running the application on additional form factors, such as rugged touchscreen tablets.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of offhand is not that simple, but would probably be useful (and certainly the only "true" way for them to test).

I'd create a service that works like the Remote Display app (part of the [WinMo Developer power tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=74473fd6-1dcc-47aa-ab28-6a2b006edfe9&displaylang=en), also ships with Platform Builder for CE), in fact it might just use that app (the source code for it actually ships with Platform Builder, so the eval version of PB would get you that source).

You would then create a web interface that acts as a "shell" for that service, marshalling the display image out to a web page and image clicks back as mouse events to the device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Scalability wouldn't be great as it still takes a full Windows OS installation just to emulate a single cradled device. Maybe use dynamic Amazon EC2 instances running a small WinXP instance to run the emulator, starting and stopping them on demand.